# PowerMock's mockStatic() overwrites X.class.y() methods

Tags: java, static, powermock, java.lang.class

MyClass.java:

```
package test;
public final class MyClass {
    public MyClass() { }
    public Package returnPackage() {
        return MyClass.class.getPackage();
    }
}
```

TestClass.java:

```
package test;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.*;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(new MyClass().returnPackage());
        mockStatic(MyClass.class);
        System.out.println(new MyClass().returnPackage());
    }
}
```

However, this results in:

```
package test
null
```

Any `MyClass.class` method call returns `null` after `PowerMockito.mockStatic(Class)`. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: What are you trying to do here.

Comment: @GarrettHall I was trying to mock a constructor

Comment: I still not understand what you are precisely trying to do. Do you want to mock a MyClass instance and you can't because it is final ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround: I can use the EasyMock-API to set up the static mocks without `PowerMockito.mockStatic()`.